# What is / is not a function inside a class

Tags: javascript

I've just started with classes on JS, and got a trouble with what is a function inside them and what is not.

```
class ficha {
    constructor() {
        let alumno;
        this.alumno="Marga";
    }
    inicio() {
        this.alumno="Norat";
    }
    verNombre() {
        return this.alumno;
    }
}
function programa() {
    let obj=new ficha();
    ficha.inicio();
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=ficha.verNombre();
}
```

Previous code gives error "ficha.inicio" and "ficha.verNombre" are not a function, and I have no clue on why. Previously i did the following code, which works ok, though I still don't see the difference with the first one.
**Error fixed, see below for the second trouble**

```
class entradaDatos {
    constructor() {
        let nombre;
        let pwd;
        this.nombre="admin";
        this.pwd="1234";
    }
    introduceDatos() {
        let valorEntrada=document.formEntrada.txtInicial.value;
        let valorPass=document.formEntrada.password.value;
        if (this.compruebaNombre(valorEntrada)) this.nombre=valorEntrada;
        else this.nombre="No válido";
        //if (this.compruebaPassword(valorPass)) this.pwd=valorPass;
        //else this.pwd="No válido";
        }
    compruebaNombre(valor) {
        let flag=true;
        if (valor==null || valor=="") flag=false;
        return flag;
    }
    compruebaPassword(pass) {
        let flag=true;
        if (pass==null || pass=="" || pass!=this.pwd) flag=flase;
        return flag;
    }
    verDatos() {
        return this.nombre;
    }
}
function programa() {
    let obj=new entradaDatos();
    obj.introduceDatos();
    $("#res").html("<br>Con jQuery: "+obj.verDatos());
    document.querySelector("#res2").innerHTML="Con JS: "+obj.verDatos();
}
```

I will take advantage of this post also to ask why if I uncomment both lines on this code it will prevent script to do anything, tecnically it does the same as on previous if/else with another var:

```
    //if (this.compruebaPassword(valorPass)) this.pwd=valorPass;
    //else this.pwd="No válido";
```

Comment: `obj.inicio()` and `obj.verNombre()`

Comment: you need to call the functions on the actual created object `obj` instead of the class definition `ficha`

Comment: ficha is the classname, obj is the instance

Comment: Static methods needs the `static` keyword (but I don't think that's what you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the methods on the object instance, not the "class":

```
obj.inicio();
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=obj.verNombre();
```

Your second example works because you do exactly that, whereas the first you are calling methods on `ficha`.

Comment: Great it was just a quick mistake and not a mislead of knowledge about classes. Any tips about the error on the second code? Is there any difference on .value of a text than on a password input?